# Does an included jsp handles the same implicit object?

Tags: jsp

I created jsp page as index.jsp,
now I included a file that is menu.jsp in index.jsp, as

```
<%@ include file="menu.jsp" %>
```

now i want to ask that, when i will access session, request, response etc. objects from menu.jsp file so will it be same of index.jsp or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will be the same, since the included JSP is still used to handle the same request, send the same response, for the same session.

Comment: Hmm. This is a static include. It just copies (at compile time) the contents of the included file (as source code) into the current JSP. As such, there is no "included JSP" really.  And if a dynamic include was used `jsp:include`, a new request instance would internally be generated for it.

Comment: Ok I got your point, so here I should not use a dynamic include if I want same request. Thanks For help.

Comment: With a dynamic include, the container will (AFAIK), create a wrapper around the original request, but that should be transparent for your JSP code: the same parameters, attributes, etc. will still be available in the request handled by the dynamically included JSP.